# plotting and manipulating boxplot x-axis labels & legend to fit to purpose using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataframe with 2 AUC columns (one calculated from the observed data and the other from simulated data). A subset of the data frame looks like this:

```
ID  AUC.OBS AUC.SIM  FED  FORM
1    100      110    0     1
1    100      110    0     1
1    105      99     0     2
2    150      140    1     1   
2    120     130     0     2
2    120     130     0     2
3    70       90     1     1
3    80       75     1     2
```

and so on. Where ID is the subject ID column. FED is whether the drug was taken on fed status (1) or Fasted status (0). FORM is specifies which drug formulation was given (1=FORM_A; 2=FORM_B).  My concern is that I want to make a boxplot for the observed and simulated AUC facetted on FED and FORM  with:

1. the x-axis of the boxplot titled as "Simulated" for simulated AUC boxplot and "Observed" for observed AUC boxplot.
2. a legend showing the "Data Source" as being "simulated" and "Observed" (for example by having two differnt colors for the observe and simulated boxplot).

I am using ggplot. I have started with the following but I am not yet getting there.

```
plotdata$ID <- as.factor(plotdata$ID)   
plotdata$FED <- as.factor(plotdata$FED)
levels(plotdata$FED) <- c("Fasted","Fed") 

plotdata$FORM <- as.factor(plotdata$FORM)
levels(plotdata$FORM) <- c("FORM_A","FORM_B")

libraray(ggplot2) 
plotobj <- NULL
plotobj <-  ggplot(data=plotdata)
plotobj <- plotobj + geom_boxplot(aes(x = ??, y = AUC.OBS), position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
plotobj <- plotobj + scale_x_discrete("?"))
plotobj <- plotobj + scale_y_continuous("AUC")
plotobj <- plotobj + ggtitle("VPC of drug exposure\n")
plotobj <- plotobj + facet_wrap(~FED+FORM, ncol=2)
plotobj
```

I would be thankfuk for your guidance on how to do modify my code to acheive this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ggplot`, happiness is achieved by getting your data in the right format: long.

```
library(reshape2)
names(plotdata)[2:3] <- c("Simulated", "Observed")
plotdata.long <- melt(plotdata, id.vars = "ID",
                      variable.name = "Data_Source", value.name = "AUC")

ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = Data_Source, color = Data_Source, y = AUC)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggtitle("VPC of drug exposure\n")
```

If you don't like the underscore, I think the easiest way to adjust labels is with `labs()`. Add to your plot:

```
labs(x = "Data Source", color = "Data Source")
```

Comment: Thank you. The code that you provided doesn't seem to be working on my data. My happiness is not yet achieved! I have modified the question to make it clearer and more representative to the actual data frame that I have. I would really appreciate if you could have a second look. Thank you.

Comment: In the `melt`, just make `id.vars = c("ID", "FED", "FORM")`.

Comment: Happiness achieved :) The melt function is a handy one! I learned good stuff from you, thanks a lot !

Comment: I want to take-off the outliers from my plot. They are too many and they squeesing the boxplot. I used: (outline=F) but it didn't work. do you have any idea why it is not taking them out with outline=F?? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the help: `?geom_bloxplot`. `outline` isn't an option, nor is `outlier`. I bet `outlier.colour = NA` will work, though you might need to adjust the axes.

Comment: Yup, that is right. `outlier.colour = NA` worked, however, this makes the outliers to disappear from the plot but the Y-axis remains the same although I am putting free-y scales. This will keep the the boxplots squeezed ! I made a little search but still couldn't find a solution.